# Regular expression string color change of decimals and integers ending with m

Tags: javascript, html, regex

I wanted to change the color of the string with m in the end For Example 
if there is a string = the car is 100m long it has 0.5m cable 
So after the match the color of 100m and 0.5m should be "red" 
Can anybody help?

Comment: I'm sorry, what? Please provide a few clear before/after examples.

Comment: What are you tried? We are going to fix your code, not write it for you.

Comment: `code` function fun()
{
  var dpattern = /[0-9](?=m)/ ;
  
  var str = document.getElementById("name").value;
  var order = dpattern.exec(str);
  
  if(order)
  {
   alert(order);
      str1 = str.replace(order, '<span style="background-color:red;">' + order + '</span>'); 
   document.getElementById("sometext").innerHTML = str1;  
   alert("valid");
    
  }
  else
  {
   alert("Not in the valid format");
   
  }
}`code` this is a function which gets a string but it only replaces the first digit before 'm' i wanted to make 0.5m red not 5m

Answer (score 1):

A regex to match those numbers could be

```
/\d+(\.\d+)?m/
```

You can then replace that match with `<span style='color: red;'>$0</span>` or something else you want.

Note, though, that in correctly typeset texts there is at least half a space between a value and its unit.

Comment: `code` function fun()
{
  var dpattern = /[0-9](?=m)/ ;
  
  var str = document.getElementById("name").value;
  var order = dpattern.exec(str);
  
  if(order)
  {
   alert(order);
      str1 = str.replace(order, '<span style="background-color:red;">' + order + '</span>'); 
   document.getElementById("sometext").innerHTML = str1;  
   alert("valid");
    
  }
  else
  {
   alert("Not in the valid format");
   
  }
}`code` this is a function which gets a string but it only replaces the first digit before 'm' i wanted to make 0.5m red not 5m

Comment: the pattern returns two strings if i pass 0.5 then it returns 0.5 and .5 if i used the exec function var order = dpattern.exec(str);

Answer (score 0):

You need to do a string replace with regex.

```
var str = 'the car is 100m long it has 0.5m cable';
var res = str.replace(/\s(\S*m)\s/gi,' <span class="red">$1</span> ');
```

Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/kWXQ8/1/

Answer (score 0):

This might do the trick:

```
var text = 'the car is 100m long it has 0.5m cable';
text = text.replace(/\d+(\.\d+)?m/g, function () {
    return '<span style="color:red;">' + arguments[0] + '</span>';
});
alert(text);
```